# Android LazyList-ListView lags on scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I'm using [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) to asynchronously load images in a list view. The example from github works just great, but when I'm using it in my application it lags massively as soon as I scroll.

Here's my code:

MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static List<EpisodeEntry> episodes;
    public static ImageLoader imageLoader;
    public ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        new GetXmlTask().execute();
    }


    private class GetXmlTask extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, List<String>> {

        private List<EpisodeEntry> episodes = new ArrayList<EpisodeEntry>();

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Boolean... booleans) {
           //xml gets parsed into ArrayList episodes
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> xml) {
            if (xml != null) {
                ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), episodes);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

    }
```

ItemAdapter:
    public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
    private final Context context;
    private final List<EpisodeEntry> values;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, List<EpisodeEntry> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        ImageView pic = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        MainActivity.imageLoader.DisplayImage("...", seriesPic);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

The FileCache, ImageLoader and MemoryCache classes are exactly the same as [here](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/tree/master/src/com/fedorvlasov/lazylist).

The images (50) are just 64x64 with a size of a few KB. Why is it lagging when scrolling in my application but not in the example application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your performance problems is probably your Adapter.

You should use the convertView if available, otherwise your adapter will inflate a new View for every item in the list.

```
View rowView = convertView;
if (rowView == null) {
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
}
```

When you scroll your list down, the Views that leave the visible are can be reused as convertView. With that code your list will inflate as many views as fit in the visible part of your list and reuse those Views when scrolling.

Also read up on [View Holder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) to further improve list performance.

Comment: Thank you, using convertView solved my issue!

But why is it so slow to create a new view?

Comment: Object allocation is always something too prevent, also views go through different processes like layout and measuring and depending on the layout, this can add up quickly